# Google app scripts - Why is my onEdit() function taking so long?

Tags: google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, range

Ok so I need to select a range that is around 350 rows and 4 columns, take the values from it and on every change in my drop down I search and compare the rows and columns from selected range and I'm finding the matches in order to filter out the drop down dataValidation's. But on every drop down change function takes around 5-6 seconds to complete.

I even tried  selecting only the small range and it still uses the same amount of time. Here in code example I'm taking a range of around 20 rows and it still takes 5-6 seconds to complete.

```
function onEdit() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EAC Input");
  var dataSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Resource names");

  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  var lastRow = dataSS.getLastRow();

  if(column == 1 || column == 2 || column == 3 || column == 4 && activeCell.getRow() > 5) {

    var makeValue = activeCell.getValue(); 

    if(makeValue == "" || makeValue == "WORKSTREAM:" || !isNaN(parseFloat(makeValue)) && isFinite(makeValue))
    {
      return;
    }

    var validationRange =  dataSS.getRange("A36:D55").getValues();

    var filteredRangeOfDepartments = [];
    var filteredRangeOfPositions = [];
    var filteredRangeOfEmployees = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < validationRange.length; i++)
    {      
      var rangeAtZero = validationRange[i][0];
      var rangeAtOne = validationRange[i][1];
      var rangeAtTwo = validationRange[i][2];

      if(rangeAtZero== makeValue)
      {
        filteredRangeOfDepartments.push(rangeAtOne);         
      }      
      if(rangeAtOne == makeValue && rangeAtZero == activeCell.offset(0, -1).getValue())
      {
         filteredRangeOfPositions.push(rangeAtTwo);        
      }
      if(rangeAtTwo == makeValue && rangeAtZero == activeCell.offset(0, -2).getValue() && rangeAtOne == activeCell.offset(0, -1).getValue())
      {
         filteredRangeOfEmployees.push(validationRange[i][3]);        
      }
    }

    if(column == 1)
    {
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(filteredRangeOfDepartments, true).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
    if(column == 2)
    {
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(filteredRangeOfPositions, true).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
    if(column == 3)
    {
      filteredRangeOfEmployees.push("TBC");
    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(filteredRangeOfEmployees, true).build();`enter code here`
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }  
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I believe you are reading cell values in every pass of the for loop.  If you could read all these into an object and work off that you will speed this up.  See the script at the bottom of the [Simple Mail Merge Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) for some useful code to retrieve data.  You are looking for all the code below the section stating _The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects' tutorial._

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried putting console.log() before and after some of the operations and still it's not clear whats taking so long. But it probably is the for loop.

Comment: @Karl_S Thanks. I'll look into it.